# Error: 1418 - While creating Mirror - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mirror

The SQL Server 2008 R2 instance has a lot of databases with mirror configuration. I'm trying to configurate the mirror for a big database comparing with the others that already have the configuration. The result when starting the mirror is "Error: 1418".

Anybody faced the same problem? I'd be more than glad with some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL SERVER - Error: 1418. The server network address can not be
>   reached or does not exist.

[What should be checked (copied from the V. Alvarez's blog):](http://sqlpost.blogspot.ru/2009/06/sql-server-error-1418-server-network.html)

> 1. The `ENDPOINTS` should have the status started.
>
> `select state_desc from sys.database_mirroring_endpoints`
>
> 2. The system should not be behind a firewall.
> 3. Make sure that the principal server instance and mirror instance are listening on the right ports and whether are available.
> 4. Name pipes protocol enabled.
> 5. The same username and password were used to run SQL Server services on both machines.
> 6. The usernames to run SQL Server services have NT Auth Access between both machines.
> 7. Make sure that the username for the SQL Server services has rights on the SQL Server instance.

Comment: Hi, John. I think I'm not facing a endpoint issue, because it already have mirror configuratiion for others databases. Just one database return de error.

Comment: Have you checked `p.5`? (username/password concordance)

Comment: Yes, I have. They use the same username/password

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is way too old, but I just faced the same problem and it took me 2 days at least to fix it.

I did go through all kind of trouble shooting and what should be checked blogs and articles.

At the end, what fixed my issue was two steps.

First I configured [the mirroring using Certificates (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/example-setting-up-database-mirroring-using-certificates-transact-sql).

Steps from that link are:

**To configure Host_A for outbound connections:**

1. On the master database, create the database master key, if needed.

   ```
   CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<1_Strong_Password!>';
   ```
2. Make a certificate for this server instance.

   ```
   CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_A_cert   
      WITH SUBJECT = 'HOST_A certificate';
   ```
3. Create a mirroring endpoint for server instance using the certificate.

   ```
   CREATE ENDPOINT Endpoint_Mirroring  
      STATE = STARTED  
      AS TCP (  
         LISTENER_PORT=7024  
         , LISTENER_IP = ALL  
      )   
      FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING (   
         AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE HOST_A_cert  
         , ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES  
         , ROLE = ALL  
      );
   ```
4. Back up the HOST_A certificate, and copy it to other system, HOST_B.

   ```
   BACKUP CERTIFICATE HOST_A_cert TO FILE = 'C:\HOST_A_cert.cer';
   ```
5. Using any secure copy method, copy C:\HOST_A_cert.cer to HOST_B.

**To configure Host_B for outbound connections**

6. On the master database, create the database master key, if needed.

   ```
   CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Strong_Password_#2>';
   ```
7. Make a certificate on the HOST_B server instance.

   ```
   CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_B_cert   
      WITH SUBJECT = 'HOST_B certificate for database mirroring';
   ```
8. Create a mirroring endpoint for the server instance on HOST_B.

   ```
   CREATE ENDPOINT Endpoint_Mirroring  
      STATE = STARTED  
      AS TCP (  
         LISTENER_PORT=7024  
         , LISTENER_IP = ALL  
      )   
      FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING (   
         AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE HOST_B_cert  
         , ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES  
         , ROLE = ALL  
      );
   ```
9. Back up HOST_B certificate.

   ```
   BACKUP CERTIFICATE HOST_B_cert TO FILE = 'C:\HOST_B_cert.cer';
   ```
10. Using any secure copy method, copy C:\HOST_B_cert.cer to HOST_A.

**To configure Host_A for inbound connections:**

11. Create a login on HOST_A for HOST_B.

    ```
    CREATE LOGIN HOST_B_login WITH PASSWORD = '1Sample_Strong_Password!@#';
    ```
12. Create a user for that login.

    ```
    CREATE USER HOST_B_user FOR LOGIN HOST_B_login;
    ```
13. Associate the certificate with the user.

    ```
    CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_B_cert  
       AUTHORIZATION HOST_B_user  
       FROM FILE = 'C:\HOST_B_cert.cer'
    ```
14. Grant CONNECT permission on the login for the remote mirroring endpoint.

    ```
    GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::Endpoint_Mirroring TO [HOST_B_login];
    ```

**To configure Host_B for inbound connections:**

15. Create a login on HOST_B for HOST_A.

    ```
    CREATE LOGIN HOST_A_login WITH PASSWORD = '=Sample#2_Strong_Password2';
    ```
16. Create a user for that login.

    ```
    CREATE USER HOST_A_user FOR LOGIN HOST_A_login;
    ```
17. Associate the certificate with the user.

    ```
    CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_A_cert  
       AUTHORIZATION HOST_A_user  
       FROM FILE = 'C:\HOST_A_cert.cer'
    ```
18. Grant CONNECT permission on the login for the remote mirroring endpoint.

    ```
    GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::Endpoint_Mirroring TO [HOST_A_login];
    ```

**Configuring the Mirroring Partners:**

1. On the mirror server instance on HOST_B, set the server instance on HOST_A as the partner (making it the initial principal server instance). Substitute a valid network address for `TCP://HOST_A.Mydomain.Corp.Adventure-Works.com:7024`

   ```
   --At HOST_B, set server instance on HOST_A as partner (principal server):  
   ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks   
       SET PARTNER = 'TCP://HOST_A.Mydomain.Corp.Adventure-Works.com:7024';
   ```
2. On the principal server instance on HOST_A, set the server instance on HOST_B as the partner (making it the initial mirror server instance). Substitute a valid network address for `TCP://HOST_B.Mydomain.Corp.Adventure-Works.com:7024`

   ```
   --At HOST_A, set server instance on HOST_B as partner (mirror server).  
   ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks   
       SET PARTNER = 'TCP://HOST_B.Mydomain.Corp.Adventure-Works.com:7024';
   ```

Now, if after all those steps you got the same error `Error: 1418`, **it would be a good try to change ports of the mirror and principal to be different** *(For example, principal: 5022, mirror: 5023)* **(This was fixed for me at least)**.